# unable to run exe file generated from pyinstaller using python windows app developed in pyqt4

Tags: python-3.x, exe, py2exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I developed an windows application using pyqt4 in anaconda env which has python 3.5 my os is windows 10.
when I tried converting into exe file using pyinstaller it is generating exe file in dist folder but when I try to run the exe file its throwing a msg box showing "Fatal error:main.py returned -1".
While running the pyinstaller command itself am getting some warnings regarding cp.win64_amd but I installed all the necessities.

your help is most appreciated.